# what does 'tc@box:/home$' mean?

Tags: command-line, prompt

I was wondering what this means? I know that CD stands for change directory does this take me to the home directory, if so what does $ mean?

Comment: What about adding a little context here? Where did you see this? Is it part of a larger script? If so, show more :-)

Comment: Gotta love people who downvote without specifying what's wrong with question or trying to improve it.

Comment: That seems to be a prompt, not a command. What does `cd` have to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

just a guess (if you are seeing this as a prompt).

```
 user@host:/pathX
```

where

- user (`tc`) your username
- host (`box`) hostname of your system
- /path (`/home`) current working dir (replaced by ~ in you home dir)
- X (usually `$` or `#` ) whether your are non root (`$`) or root (`#`).

Answer (score 1):

What you see is command line prompt. It usually looks more or less like this:

username@hostname:yourlocation

Last character(`#` or `$`) means you're either root, or non-root.

However, you can change the prompt. The value of the prompt is held under `PS1` value:

```
echo $PS1
```

You will notice many strange characters. These are some formatting characters that allow you to input things like user name or hostname, instead of hard-coding them.

You can change it yourself, if you want:

```
PS1="yourtext"
```

Note how it won't change if you set it to some ordinary string. Changing it like so will only affect it temporary - will work for your current terminal session. You can add it to your `.bashrc` if you want to change it (almost) permanently.

[More info about customization can be found here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)